# Views - Wrapper Fields in DIV after ROW class

Tags: views

Have this:

```
<div class="ROW CLASS">
      <div class="views-field"></div>
      <div class="views-field"></div>
      <div class="views-field"></div>
      <div class="views-field"></div>
</div>
```

And need this:

```
<div class="ROW CLASS">
   <div class="FIELDS CONTAINER">
          <div class="views-field"></div>
          <div class="views-field"></div>
          <div class="views-field"></div>
          <div class="views-field"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you start editing your view, on the right side under the advanced options you will find Theme: information. You will see the currently used template files and the candidate files.
My solution would be to overwrite the default template files with your own. That way you could simply add a wrapper around $rows.